# How to get the list in controller through jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, liferay

I have a jsp page , from which I am getting the list of the checkboxes selected by a user.

And as per the selected checkboxes I want to call my controller using the jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="XYZ" value="hello1"/>Hello1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="XYZ" value="hello2"/>Hello2<br>
```

I obtained all the values in the jQuery and set all the parameters into a variable as given below.

```
var allVals = [];   
$("input[name=XYZ]:checked").each(function() {
    allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
```

and I am using an AUI to call my controller, I am passing the value as parameter.

```
AUI().use('aui-base',
          'aui-io-request',
          'liferay-portlet-url',
                    function(A) {
                        var A = AUI();
            var myResourceURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
        myResourceURL.setResourceId('getABC');
        myResourceURL.setParameter("action",'ZYX');
        myResourceURL.setPortletId(pid);
        myResourceURL.setParameter("list",allVals);

                    A.io.request(myResourceURL.toString(),
                    {
                    method : 'post',
                    dataType : 'text',
                    on : {
                            start : function() {
.
.
.});
```

And in my controller I want to obtain the list and my controller is like this:

```
System.out.println(request.getParamter("list"));
```

This statement is just giving me the first selected element, not the complete list of the elements.

Is there something I am missing , or any other way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to go with 'getParameterNames()' instead  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames()

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for thr document shared. I tried String[] list = request.getParameterValues("list"); and it worked for me.